# Finding all attribute values in LDAP

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I would like to write an LDAP query which finds all possible values of an attribute. I have a list of most of the values but I want to search for any remaining values.

The difficulty is that excluding values in the usual way

```
(!(|(attrib=foo)(attrib=bar)(attrib=baz)))
```

removes entries which have these values in addition to the new values I'm trying to find. Is there a way to avoid this behavior? I don't want to download and process everything (it would work, but take lots of time and bandwidth).

Comment: Eh? If you exclude attribute values in the filter, entries with those attribute values are excluded from the search. That's what the syntax you're using  is for. If you don't want that, don't do it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I'm looking for syntax that will allow me to search for values other than an enumerated list, or else confirmation that this is not possible with an LDAP query. I know that queries like the one I gave won't do what I want (that's why I asked the question). If you can confirm that this is not possible write it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score -1):

For "Finding all attribute values in LDAP
"
Use the presence filter:

```
(attrib=*)
```

Comment: You may as well nit filter at all.

Comment: This is essentially what I've done up to this point. But there's a lot of data and I'd prefer to avoid clobbering the server. This might be the only way but I'd like to know more.